# Estimating mass proportions from fractional samples

Tags: estimation, sampling

Say you are on a beach that is composed of a mixture of different colored sands (for simplicity, black and white) and you wish to estimate how much there is of each type. You have a bucket that you can use to take samples of the sand and a technique to separate the different types and weigh them. Say also that the beach is not too big, so you know the fractional amount of sand in your bucket samples compared to the total sand on the beach.

Let the true fractional portion of white sand on the beach be called $w^*$, and therefore (in this two-type case) the true amount of black sand be $(1 - w^*)$. Our bucket samples give weights $\{w_i\} = w_1, w_2, …, w_n$. I'd like to estimate the distribution of $w^*$ given my measurements $\{w_i\}$. Assume the sand is iid uniformly at random across the beach and that the bucket samples are taken without replacement.

Can anyone give me some direction on how to model this problem? I would ultimately like to generalize to more than two types of sand, but the two-type case, even with just a single sample, should at least get me started.

I began trying to consider the sampling as a Bernoulli process, but I ran into trouble with understanding how to deal with the non-integer nature of the samples: i.e., the measurement values are continuous-valued masses, rather than some sort of count.

Comment: Are you thinking of this as Bayesian? From a frequentist perspective, $w*$ would be a fixed value, & not have a "distribution". A couple of other thoughts, I suspect the sampling without replacement & the fact that the beach is finite will make this problem harder than it would be w/ a more typical setup. I don't know it those issues are a big part of what you want to understand here. Lastly, you're right that the binomial distribution is used for discrete Bernoulli trials; the [beta distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) is often helpful for continuous proportions.

Comment: $w^*$ certainly only has one value in reality. I'm looking for what I can say about its possible values based on the measurement(s) taken though, which I guess is a Bayesian perspective. The finite nature of the beach and the sampling without replacement aren't really big deals. They are true of my real problem, but an approach that assumed them away would still be useful.